# Which is a good cross-browser date picker for use with MVC, bootstrap, razor, using EditorFor ?

Tags: date, razor, model-view-controller, datepicker, editorfor

I have tried a number of datepickers now but they have not worked as needed.

I need to be able to change to date format, in particular I need to use dd/mm/yyyy mm/dd/yyyy and yyyy/mm/dd

It needs to work properly with the dd/mm/yyyy date format in Firefox, Edge, IE, Chrome and Opera.

I want to be able to apply the same look and feel as the rest of the web application (bootstrap, razor views)

I want, if possible, to use this with EditorFor in the view. If not, I need to give it the same look and feel using an alternative, which I am not sure how to achieve.

I have wasted so much time trying some datepickers, (including bootstrap.v3.datepicker) only for them not to work properly in the different browsers. Can anyone suggest a solution that works and meets this criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery UI:
[jQueryUI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

It works with most modern browsers last time I checked and you can change the date format.

Hope that works for you :)